# Why can't I open get 8 processes at a time?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, message-passing

I'm a beginner to MPI. When I coded my first program, I came into a tough problem to me.

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv) ; 
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank) ; 
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size)  ;
printf("Process: %d\n", rank);
printf("Procs_num: %d\n", size);
```

and:

```
mpicc main.c -o main 
mpirun -np 8 main
```

But all I get is 8 duplicates of:

```
Process: 0
Procs_num: 1
```

What I expect to get is:

```
Process: 0~7 
Procs_num: 8
```

I guess it is because there is no 8 processes in MPI_COMM_WORLD, but I cannot figure out the reason and have no idea about how to solve it.

And I hope you will catch what I want to express. Many thx!!

Comment: Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039608/why-do-all-my-open-mpi-processes-have-rank-0.  You probably have more than one MPI library installed, and the `mpicc` command is coming from one, and `mpirun` from the other.

Comment: @GregInozemtsev may be. I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you forgot to call `MPI_Finalize`

Here is the correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h> 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv) ; 
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank) ; 
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size)  ;
    printf("Process: %d\n", rank);
    printf("Procs_num: %d\n", size);

    MPI_Finalize();                         

   return(0);
}
```

Then you get your 8 fifferents ranks:

```
~/mpi_tests/examples > mpirun -np 8 ~/mpi_tests/examples/t
Process: 4
Procs_num: 8
Process: 5
Procs_num: 8
Process: 0
Procs_num: 8
Process: 1
Procs_num: 8
Process: 7
Procs_num: 8
Process: 2
Procs_num: 8
Process: 3
Procs_num: 8
Process: 6
Procs_num: 8
```

Comment: Omitting `MPI_FINALIZE` might make an MPI program enter an undefined state (and often crash) when one of the processes exits without calling `MPI_FINALIZE` but it would not lead to the behaviour, described by the OP.